# Determine the nature of an isolated singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Using the Laurent series, determine the nature of the isolated singularity $z = \pi$ for the function

$$f(z) = \frac{1-e^{-z}}{\sin{z}}$$

---

$$e^{-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_1^{(n)}(\pi)\frac{(z-\pi)^n}{n!} = e^{-\pi} - e^{-\pi}(z-\pi) + e^{-\pi}\frac12(z-\pi)^2 - e^{-\pi}\frac16(z-\pi)^3 + \ldots$$

$$\sin{z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_2^{(n)}(\pi)\frac{(z-\pi)^n}{n!}=-(z-\pi)+\frac16(z-\pi)^3 -\frac1{120}(z-\pi)^5+\ldots $$

So we may write

\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{1-e^{-\pi} + e^{-\pi}(z-\pi) - e^{-\pi}\frac12(z-\pi)^2 + e^{-\pi}\frac16(z-\pi)^3 - \ldots}{-(z-\pi)+\frac16(z-\pi)^3 -\frac1{120}(z-\pi)^5+\ldots} \\
&= \frac{1}{z-\pi} \frac{1-e^{-\pi} + e^{-\pi}(z-\pi) - e^{-\pi}\frac12(z-\pi)^2 + e^{-\pi}\frac16(z-\pi)^3 - \ldots}{-1+\frac16(z-\pi)^2 -\frac1{120}(z-\pi)^4+\ldots} \\
&\to \frac{1}{z-\pi} (e^{-\pi}-1) \quad \text{as $z\to\pi$.}
\end{align}

Hence $z=\pi$ is a simple pole of $f$.

---

My question is: Does this look correct? Is there an easier way to do this (less computationally involved) still using the Laurent Series method?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the limit $$\lim_{z\to \pi}(z-\pi)\frac{1-e^{-z}}{\sin(z)}$$Using L'Hospital's Rule, this become $e^{-\pi}-1$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Ah ok. So can you tell me of the possible cases which can occur? Say, if $$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z) = 0$$ what happens then? More generally, if $$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)^Nf(z)=c\not=0$$ exists then is $z=a$ a pole of order $N$? And if $$\lim_{z\to a} f(z)=c\not=0$$ is $z=a$ a removable singularity (also what happens if $c=0$ here)? Then I take it, if the limit doesn't exists $z=a$ is an essential singularity?

Comment: Further to my previous comment. If $$\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)^N f(z) = 0$$ then do we check $$\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)^{N-1} f(z) = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1-e^{-z}}{\sin z}=\frac{1-e^{-\pi} e^{-(z-\pi)}}{(z-\pi)\left(-1+\frac{(z-\pi)^2}6+\ldots\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{1-e^{-\pi}(1-(z-\pi)+\frac{(z-\pi)^2}2-\ldots}{-(z-\pi)}\left(1+\frac{(z-\pi)^2}6+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1-e^{-\pi}+e^{-\pi}(z-\pi)-\ldots}{-(z-\pi)}\left(1+\frac{(z-\pi)^2}6+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac{1-e^{-\pi}}{-(z-\pi)}+e^{-\pi}+\ldots$$

Thus, $\;z=\pi\;$ is a simple pole with residue $\;-(1-e^{-\pi})=e^{-\pi}-1\;$.

**Another way** :

$$\lim_{z\to\pi}(z-\pi)\frac{1-e^{-z}}{\sin z}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{1-e^{-z}+(z-\pi)e^{-z}}{\cos z}=e^{-\pi}-1$$

Comment: Ah, got that darn mistake! The power series for $\;\sin z\;$ about $\;z=\pi\;$ begins as $\;-z+\frac{(z-\pi)^3}{3!}-\ldots\;$ , and **not** $\;z-\frac{(z-\pi)^3}{3!}+\ldots$